# Change checkbox attr onclick of parent div

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I have a php script that outputs images, at the moment to select an image you have to click a checkbox. I want to change this so that when the parent div is clicked the checkbox is set to checked.

I know how to do this if i have a different id for the parent div, and the class seems to be no good as it would set all of the checkboxs the php has outputted as true/false.

this is what i have so far:

JQuery

```
$('#div').bind('click', function() {
   var checkbox = $(this).find(':checkbox');

    checkbox.attr('checked', !checkbox.attr('checked'));
});
```

HTML (Outputted by php, so multiples exist.)

```
<div id="div" style='display:inline-block; padding:15px;' class='lifted drop-shadow-sq'>
    <img class='reflect reflect-br'  width='150px' height='150px' src=\"thumb.php?id=$id\">
        <input type='checkbox' class=\"show-man\" name=\"images[]\" value='$id'>
</div>
```

So how would i set the checkbox as checked when the parent div is clicked in a way that wouldn't cause conflict between any other checkbox?

thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Is there more than one checkbox per DIV?

Comment: There is only the one checkbox in each parent div @ Kevin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>Your selector is wrong there is no element with ID of `div` in your markup,</strike> you can use `prop` method:

```
$('div').on('click', function() {
   $('input[type=checkbox]', this).prop('checked', function(i, checked){
      return !checked
   })
});
```

Please note that `:checkbox` selector is deprecated and IDs must be unique, if you have multiple elements with the same IDs your markup is invalid and your ID selector only selects the first element with that specific ID, you should use classes instead.

```
$('.div').on('click', function() {
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to type in an id attr on the example html here, i'll do that now. @ undifined.

Comment: Wouldn't this cause issues, as each div outputted by the php would have the same id?

Comment: @user1636816: It should matter as the solution doesn't use ids, but having your php script output HTML with non-unique IDs is bad practice to start with and you ought to fix it (on the PHP side).

Comment: Yer that's what i was getting at above in the main description, using an id would result in only the first outputted div being able to be checked upon click, but then the use of classes would result in all being checked upon click, right?

Comment: @user1636816 No, only the clicked element is the target of the event. Not all the element with that class name.

Comment: Ah matt, so if i was to increment the ID on the php side, then on the Jquery side, they would match and issue solved?

Comment: @user1636816 Use classes, in that case you should use Attribute Selector for selecting the element.

Comment: Why are you reinventing the wheel, HTML does this for you. There is zero need for JavaScript!

Comment: @undefined, Since when is a image in a label not valid? Validates fine for me on W3C validator for an HTML5 document

Comment: It is also valid in HTML4. It is better than adding a click event for every div. A better solution is to put the click event on the document level so there is only one. But a label will make the form accessible with proper text. Simple 508 improvements developers ignore.

Comment: Eric is right there is no need for JavaScript in this case.  There is also an argument for semantics.  Use a `<label>`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there isn't more than 1 checkbox per div, and that each check-box implements the same class, you can use the following jQuery:

```
$('input[type=checkbox].show-man').each(function(index, value) {
    var self = $(this);
    self.parent().on("click", function() { 
        self.prop('checked', !self.prop('checked'));
    });
});
```

As an explanation, `$('input[type=checkbox].show-man')` should grab all of the checkboxes that are relevant (so you would still be able to have other checkboxes and divs on the page that are unaffected). Then the `each()` method would go through and grab each parent of each checkbox and assign the click event to it to toggle the checked status of the relevant checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Why reinvent the wheel!

The [HTML label element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/label) when clicked will change the checkbox state. Use a label instead and there is no need for JavaScript.

```
<label for="cb" style='display:inline-block; padding:15px;' class='lifted drop-shadow-sq'>
    <img class='reflect reflect-br'  width='150px' height='150px' src=\"thumb.php?id=$id\">
        <input id="cb" type='checkbox' class=\"show-man\" name=\"images[]\" value='$id'>
</label>
```

​